# How to get records which is based on another table attributes for order in sequelize typescript

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

So here I want to get a list of buses based on stops.time for this:

SQL QUERY :

```
SELECT buses.*
FROM buses
ORDER BY (
  SELECT MIN(stops.time) FROM stops WHERE stops.bus_id = buses.id
)
```

So could you give a solution that how to write queries in Sequelize Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

I guess as per the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#ordering) you could write it as

```
Buses.findAll({
  order: [
    [Buses.associations.Stops, sequelize.fn('min', sequelize.col('time')), 'DESC']
  ]
})
```

> Will order by an associated model's attribute using an association object. (preferred method)